# Sinatra blank page

Tags: ruby, sinatra, torquebox

My code is:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'jdbc/postgres'
require 'sequel'
require 'logger'
require 'json'
require 'sinatra/reloader'

class DemoApiApp < Sinatra::Application
  #set :show_exceptions, false

  configure :development do
    register Sinatra::Reloader
  end

  #connect to the database
  DB ||= Sequel.connect(ENV['data_source'])
  #DB2 ||= Sequel.connect(ENV['data_source_2'])
  #Sequel::Model.db = DB2
  #DB.loggers << $logger if $logger
  #DB.log_warn_duration = 2 #0.2
  #DB.sql_log_level = :debug

  set :views, 'views/demo_api/'

  get'/api_docs' do
    @nav_title = "API Documentation"
    @title = "API Documentation"
    @css ="dental"
    @dir ="api_docs"
    erb :demo_api_layout
  end

  get'/?' do
    @nav_title = "Plan A Member Portal - Medical"
    @title = "Medical Cost Estimator"
    @css = "medical"
    @dir = "medical/demo_api_index"
    @main_color = "2E57A1"
    @secondary_color = "353EA8"
    @txt_color = "0F2F69"
    @focus_color = "7E9BD0"
    @deductible = 5000
    @zip = 12211
    @proc = 33010
    @in_charge = 50
    @in_reimburse = 0
    @common_conditions = [{"key"=>"workbook", "description"=>"Cost Profile", "procs"=>[ ["33010"], ["93000"], ["80061"] ]}]
    erb :demo_api_layout
  end

end


# Dir.glob(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) + '/{helpers,controllers,models}/*.rb'). each { | file | require file }

require 'demo_api_controller'
# require 'models'

end
```

when I visit the site, it shows blank page though. Any help?

Edit 1: contents of demo_api_layout.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Uncomment to make IE8 render like IE7 -->
  <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /> -->

  <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title><%= @title %></title>

  <!-- Included CSS Files -->
   <link href="/css/stylesheets/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="/css/stylesheets/foundation_icons_general/stylesheets/general_foundicons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

   <!-- foundation css override file -->
   <link href="/css/stylesheets/overrides/foundation_and_overrides_<%= @css %>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 


  <!-- Included JS Files  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <%= erb :navbar %>

  <%= erb :"#{@dir}" %>

  <%= erb :footer %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What’s in `demo_api_layout.erb`?

Comment: Also, you should extend from `Sinatra::Base`, not `Sinatra::Application`.

Comment: @matt - just shared demo_api_layout.erb content

Comment: You’ll need to add the other templates too (`navbar.erb`, `footer.erb` and whatever `dir` points to. You’re also using templates in an odd way – is there a reason you’re not using layouts?

Comment: I have those files. When I go to abc.com/demo_api.rb, it prints the file. Do you know why?

Comment: I mean add them to the answer, as they have the content that you should see. Although from your comment it looks like something else is going on. Do you see the title in title bar of your browser when you go to the site?

Comment: @matt - no, it gives a complete blank page. Also, when I go to abc.com/demo_api.rb - it prints the above code contents.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49778/discussion-between-dang-and-matt)